# Добрый день. Какая-то ошибка с импортом ReactDom, просто ни с чего ни с того начало выдавать ошибку

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Вот сам текст ошибки "Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports." Я сейчас учусь по одному курсу, и там показывали как делать Context API. Импорты и React Dom я не трогал, но всё равно перестало работать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка говорить о том что ваша функция `rerenderEntireTree` ничего не возврашает.

```js
const rerenderEntireTree = () => {
  // вы использовали фигурные скобки, поэтому вам нужно использовать ключевое слово "return"
  return ReactDom.render(
    ...
  )
}
```

или вот так

```js
const rerenderEntireTree = () => ReactDom.render(
  ...
)
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.Но Ничего не вышло, к сожалению. Ошибка все та же самая.

Comment: скинте ссылку на codesandbox где будет ваш код. чтобы я смог именно видет ошибку и сразу решеть ее.